# Excel values to sharepoint multi check box through powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I have in my excel one column name Country with Multiple values like This 
[image]
I want to read the values from excel and update the choice field in sharepoint through powershell. 
Below code Works fine and it updates the field in sharepoint view. However when i edit the item the multi choice field is not selected . Below is the screen shot for the same[image]

Code is like Below

```
$sInputFile="C:\PopulateList\New folder\Countries.csv"
 #Adding the Client OM Assemblies        
        $sCSOMRuntimePath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"        
        $sCSOMPath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"             
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMPath         
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMRuntimePath       

        #SPO Client Object Model Context
        $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl)
        $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUserName, $sPassword)  
        $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials
        $spoList = $spoCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($sListName)
        $spoCtx.Load($spoList)  

        $tblItems = Import-CSV $sInputFile  
        foreach ($sItem in $tblItems) 
        {

         try{

            $spoListItemCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
            $spoListItem=$spoList.AddItem($spoListItemCreationInformation)


            $Countries=$sItem.Country.ToString();

            #when i Write-host i get countries like this "U.K,Australia" for the first Record


            $spoListItem["Country"]=$Countries ;

            $spoListItem.Update()
            $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

            }

            catch{
            write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red

            }


        }
```

Comment: Is this a choice field? Try delimiting the values you’re writing with `;#` so you write a string like this: `;#U.K.;#Australia;#`

Comment: Yes, choice field with multi values selection.If I take an array an hard code the vales like this    countr ,=@( "U.k", AUSTRALIA") it works. But from an excel column how can I format likethis